# Qt - why is QTableView losing its model()?

Tags: c++, qt

I can't find anything that could cause this. I have Buttons and TableViews defined in my UI form.

Then I do:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    if (!createConnection(this))
        printf("%s\n", "Unable to set up database!");

    QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    model->setTable(tableName);
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    model->select();

    table->setModel(model);
    // At this point both model and table->model return same thing (proper model).
}
```

But then I have:

```
void MainWindow::on_save_clicked()
{
    QTableView* current = (QTableView*) ui->tables->currentWidget();
    // current table is correctly found.
    QSqlTableModel* model = (QSqlTableModel*) current->model();
    // model is null
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Maybe `ui->tables->currentWidget()` is not the same as `table`.

Comment: @drescherjm Damn, objectName() got me confused (they were same). You are right, one is container, other is table (in that container).

Answer (score 0):

As @drescherjm pointed out.

My Tabs were actually containers for Tables inside them and currentWidget returned them, not the tables themselves. This can be fixed either by putting tables straight to Tabs or by creating wrapping class that has a pointer to data needed.